# Python : How to replace particular value in dat file?

Tags: python, csv, parsing

i have this data in dat file,

```
arun    20     123
rahul   34     456
```

i want replace 34 as 38. Like,

```
arun    20     123
rahul   38     456
```

Fletching all data in list and updating and writing complete data in dat file doesn't look efficient. I want to replace the particular value and save it.

Comment: Are you using csv module?

Comment: yes @MohamedThasinah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With plain files you have no other solutions than reading the whole content and rewriting it. Note that for a simple short csv file this won't hardly have any performance issues.

The other solution is to use a database, but I doubt it will be much more efficient for two records with three fields each. Also, updating records in a database DO require both write and read operations too, obviously.

Comment: Its not limited to 2 or 3 records,,, just for example i made that,,, it involves more records,,

Comment: If you have hundreds of records or more and concurrent processes need to update them concurrently then use a proper database.

Comment: Okay. In xml file, it is

Comment: How is xml any better than csv or any other file-based text format ?

Comment: sorry. i didn't make previous comment properly. is it possible to do this xml file ?

Comment: Yes but it won't make any difference (except possibly degrade performances wrt/ a csv file). That's how files work, period.